# Check BIND version in CentOS

Tags: centos, bind

According to the manpage, the option `-v` will report the version number. But when I use `/etc/init.d/named -v` it outputs the following:

`Usage: /etc/init.d/named {start|stop|status|restart|condrestart|reload|probe}`

I am using CentOS 5.7 on a VPS, with WHM/cPanel.

Comment: To be specific, scripts in /etc/init.d are startup scripts for the services, so what you did was pass the "-v" option to the script. The script obviously doesn't understand the "-v" option.  If you didn't already have the answer from Mike, you can read the script to see what the actual executable being called from the script would be.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

that is how you start bind via the init.d script.. not the binary itself

```
/usr/sbin/named -v
```

Answer (score 7):

Mike's answer will work. Also: **yum info packagename** will tell you about any package, just replace *packagename* with the piece of software you'd like to learn about.